# How to include library file in blade view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-blade

I have included php-excel library in path root_path/libraries/php-excel. I want to include excel library file in blade template. Right now i have written:-

```
/** PHPExcel root directory */
 if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) 
 {
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . 'PHPExcel/Autoloader.php');
 }
```

Is it a correct way. How should i include file in blade view?

Comment: I suggest you to use Composer, install with composer and use your excel function in your conroller.  Do not violate MVC pattern .

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
}
```

After that just execute `composer update`.

Comment: `phpexcel/phpexcel` is deprecated. Use `phpoffice/phpexcel`.